# Installed fresh wordpress 5.8 but why Jquery library don't show on frontend of twenty twentyone wordpress theme?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Installed Fresh wordpress version 5.8
Theme active - Twenty Twentyone

Problem - Jquery library doesn't load on front-end.

Tried to run few Jquery commands in header.php but error generates in Inspect element tool saying "Jquery is not defined". I understand by default wordpress comes bundled with Jquery which is included in wp-includes directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

The Problem was related to wordpress Twenty Twentyone theme. Wordpress actually comes bundled with Jquery but the new Twenty Twentyone theme doesn't include code to enable/register Jquery. I placed a code in functions.php to register Jquery with this theme and now the Jquery is loading on frontend.

Here is I used in functions.php

```
function load_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); # Loading the WordPress bundled jQuery version.
    //may add more scripts to load like jquery-ui
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

The Previous wordpress theme like Twenty Sixteen , Twenty Thirteen always had this code implemented in functions.php file so we always got Jquery library loading at front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Typo? Jquery() vs. jQuery().

Otherwise, try viewing source and clicking through to the linked jQuery file. The WP hosting environment could play a part here in whether the file is linking correctly.

** update - great you managed to sort it!